# How to get Resource Availability Statuses with Azure Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk, azure-rest-api

I want to find out the availability status of a resource in Azure.
There is a REST API available for [Resource Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses).

How is it possible to call this endpoint with the [Azure Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using `com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager:2.2.0`.
Following code loads the availability status of an Azure Key Vault.

```java
TokenCredential credentials = InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder().build();
AzureResourceManager resourceManager = AzureResourceManager
    .configure()
    .authenticate(credentials, AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE))
    .withDefaultSubscription();

String resourceGroup = "resource-group-name";
String keyVaultName = "key-vault-name";

GenericResource resource = resourceManager.genericResources().get(
    resourceGroup,
    "Microsoft.KeyVault",
    "vaults/" + keyVaultName + "/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth",
    "availabilityStatuses", 
    "/current",
    "2020-05-01"
);

// Map containing the availabilityState
resource.properties();
```